# Как упростить массив?

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

```
var array=function() {
    array=[1,3,5,7,9,11];
    console.log(array[3]); 
    console.log(array.length);
}
array();
```

Comment: Что значит упростить?

Comment: как сократить код,что бы не создавать переменную в начале?

Comment: @Sagaydak1411 попробуйте вызвать функцию `array` еще раз :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял вопрос:

```js
var array = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11];
console.log(array[3]);
console.log(array.length);
```

Comment: да,благодарю,оно)